# Moving from another page instead of index.php during debuggin with XDEBUG

Tags: php, netbeans-7, xdebug

I am trying to debug my application,

but the problem i am facing with is, i want to debug a page that is in the middle of the application, and whenever i am trying to start xdebug in my Netbeans IDE; its start from the first page `index.php` that takes a long time to locate that page :(

Is there any settings in Netbeasn so that i can debug any page instead of `index.php` if yes then how can i implement it on my IDE?

Netbeans Version: 7.2
PHP : 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try using breakpoints in the script you need to start looking into.

Select the first line (or the line you expect script to stop at), click with the mouse on the left side bar on this line or press (Ctrl/Cmd + F8) and start the debugger. When it'll stop in the index.php just press Resume (F9) to stop at the breakpoint.

If you don't like that debugging stops at the first line of your script you can uncheck the "Force break at the first line when..." box under PHP -> Debug -> Xdebug tabs.

Comment: i tried according to you, but its still start from the index.php, what i want, to start the debugger from admin.php not the index.php

Comment: Please uncheck: Tools->Options->Php->General Options->Stop at the First Line.

Comment: but i didn't find this kind of option,, http://tinypic.com/r/2zrguhx/5 this is the scrnshoot of the General Tab

Comment: Sorry, the checkbox moved to Debugging tab someday :)

Comment: after doing this the netbeans hide the move buttons of the debugging options take a look on the scrnshoot http://tinypic.com/r/33l11xc/5

Comment: The script is still doing something somewhere and haven't reached the breakpoint. Try placing more breakpoint to the code to determine where the loop starts.